# IBM i (as/400) clarifications

Tags: discussion

Can we make the tag ibm-midrange and iseries the alias? iSeries is a decade old, but autocorrect in the tag field suggests it..

Also, should there be a DB2-fo-IBM-i tag for issue that are specific to the IBM i flavor of DB2, like calling RPG as a stored procedure?

Comment: I assume there are situational differences in the products that would warrant making version specific tags?

Comment: Yes, for example, you can call an RPG program as a stored procedure in  DB2 on the IBM i. There also seems to be less XML support. Thirdly, the networking protocol is different. You need a difference JDBC or whatever driver. Finally, you have other artifacts of dealing with tables on the green screen as Physical files, and "long column names"

Comment: There is often confusion with the Midrange version (DB2 for i)  vs DB2 LUW and DB2/z.  The most frequent problem is that people think they are interchangeable because they're all branded 'DB2'.  The most common question: 'What version of DB2 is DB2 for i?'  A: There is no version; it's utterly integrated with the operating system and if you're asking about a version you're trying to install something for IBM i that belongs on LUW or z.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you're proposing. I can't parse it as currently written.

Comment: I had no idea anyone would call AS/400 stuff "midrange" in 2015.  iSeries replaced AS400 in common parlance, but has the "midrange" name actually documented ANYWHERE? It's "IBM i" on their website.